# Umbraco UrlRewrite - same page, different querystring parameters

Tags: url-rewriting, umbraco

Looking for some help with setting up al UrlRewrite for the same page with different querystring parameters.

Below are the two urls that I am looking to rewrite

```
stockists.aspx?product=1&fragrance=2
stockists.aspx?store=1
```

I setup the url rewrite for *stockists.aspx?product=1&fragrance=2* (in config/UrlRewriting.config) first and tested successfully.

```
<add name="Stockists"
  virtualUrl="^~/stockists/(.*)/(.*).aspx"
  rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
  destinationUrl="~/stockists.aspx?product=$1&amp;fragrance=$2"
  ignoreCase="true" />
```

I then setup the url rewrite for *stockists.aspx?store=1* (in config/UrlRewriting.config) and now neither url rewrite works.

```
<add name="Stores"
  virtualUrl="^~/stockists/(.*).aspx"
  rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
  destinationUrl="~/stockists.aspx?store=$1"
  ignoreCase="true" />
```

Any suggestions on how the above can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is now, the Stores rewrite would also match the url format that the Stockists rewrite is matching. `(.*)` matches any number of any characters. To fix this, each `(.*)` should be changed to `([^/]+)`. That will match any character except a forward slash and also makes sure that there is at least one character.

```
<add name="Stockists"
  virtualUrl="^~/stockists/([^/]+)/([^/]+).aspx"
  rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
  destinationUrl="~/stockists.aspx?product=$1&amp;fragrance=$2"
  ignoreCase="true" />

<add name="Stores"
  virtualUrl="^~/stockists/([^/]+).aspx"
  rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
  destinationUrl="~/stockists.aspx?store=$1"
  ignoreCase="true" />
```

Now, this might not completely solve the problem, but it should allow the Stockists rewrite to work again. I suspect there is something else wrong with the Stores rewrite, but the Stockists rewrite stopped working because the url pattern was matched by the Stores rewrite.